# Translations are not working after adding http interceptor in ionic/angular

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular-http-interceptors, ngx-translate

The translations are working fine in local machine. But when i generate the apk using ionic and install it in device it's not working. It is throwing an error.

I added the code below. Please correct me if something is missing

// THIS IS THE CODE I AM USING FOR HTTP INTERCEPTOR

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpHandler, HttpErrorResponse, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import consts from './consts';

@Injectable()
export class ApiHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router, public http: HttpClient, public storage: Storage) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.storage.get('token');
    const refreshToken = this.storage.get('refresh-token');

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // Accept: 'application/json',
      },
      url: request.url.indexOf('http') >= 0 ? request.url : consts.API_URL + request.url,
    });

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        return event;
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('HttpErrorResponse', error);
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.storage.clear();
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
        return throwError(error);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

// THIS IS THE CODE I AM USING FOR TRANSLATIONS LOADER

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

// THIS IS THE CODE I AM USING IN MY app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'en',
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot({ name: 'da-merchant', driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql'] }),
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    Events,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ApiHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

### Environment

```
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.6",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.0",
    "@mdi/font": "^5.5.55",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

**The issue here is only when i run the ionic app in device after installing the apk. As i mentioned, in local env it's working fine.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with this line:

```
request.url.indexOf('http') >= 0 ? request.url : consts.API_URL + request.url
```

In case of Ionic, the page runs in a local web server running at some localhost port. The translations URL is relative to the current URL and therefore given without a 'http'. Your code therefore sends this request to the backend.

If I were you, I would remove this line of code and just set the correct URL at the point of calling. Like wherever you are calling your backend, you could just write `consts.API_URL + '...'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint @MauriceNino

I fixed it by the below code

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  const path = window.location.origin + '/assets/i18n/';
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, path, '.json');
}
```

The issue was with the path/url. In local env it hits **https://localhost:8100/** but in real device it is hitting **https://localhost/** only. There is no port number.

I am answering it myself as it might help someone who has similar issue.